# Generate picture in random <td>

Tags: javascript, html

so in my HTML, i have a table with 64  tags and what I want to do is to make 10 random  display a certain picture. This is what I have so far. How do i display the image inside the ? (Javascript only). Thanks in advance.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = "sweeperbomb.png";


    function generateBombs()
    {
        constants = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,]
        numOfBombs = 0;
        BOMB = 9;

        while (numOfBombs != 10)
        {
            i = Math.floor(Math.random()*constants.length);

            if (constants[i] != BOMB)
            {
            constants[i] = BOMB;
            numOfBombs++;
            }
        }
    }


    </script>
```

Comment: Are you using a library such as jQuery? Or do you have to do it all yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is completely untested but should do the job, good luck

```
function generateBombs()
{
    var targetTable = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0],
        used = [],
        bomb = 0,
        x,
        y;

    while (bomb <= 9) {
        y = Math.round(Math.random() * 7);
        x = Math.round(Math.random() * 7);
        if (used.indexOf(y + ':' + x) === -1) {
            targetTable.getElementsByTagName('tr')[y]
                .getElementsByTagName('td')[x]
                .innerHTML = '<img src="bomb.png" />';
            used.push(y + ':' + x);
            bomb++;
        }
    }
}

generateBombs();
```

**JSFiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/pfxpcoe0/

Comment: This works but the amount of bombs each time i refreshed is random from 0-8. Is there a way to make it always 8? Thank you =)

Comment: But every time i refresh the page, theres always a different amount of bombs ranging from 0-10

Comment: Ahhh, @StingBulb.  I found a bug in my code.  It has been updated to work every time now

Comment: What happens if you get the same random _x_ and _y_ as a previous iteration?

Comment: Thats what the `used` array is for.  If the x and y have already been generated and used.  It ignores them and genereates a new one without incrementing `bomb`